# securing user account microservice with spring

Tags: java, rest, spring-security, architecture, microservices

I'm creating a microservice structured application using 3 spring-boot microservices:

- web - handle incoming web requests for clients
- user-account - manage clients accounts and logins
- products - manage clients products

The web microservice lets a client register/login and sends REST requests to the user-account microservice to manage their account details and login. It also lets a logged in client get and add products that are associated to their account via REST requests to the products microservice.

That was the plan anyway. I've been looking into security and have added spring security to the web microservice for clients logging in. I've also added a jwt token to a header when the client logs in and was going to use that as the authentication for accessing the products microservice (which will be otherwise locked down with spring security).

Assuming that all sounds reasonable, the thing i'm unsure of is how I should be locking down the user-account microservice. I need to be able to make REST requests to it from the web microservice to attempt to login users, register users etc. Should the web microservice send an authentication token with a fixed system user details to the user-accounts microservice and then lock down all other REST access to the user-accounts microservice using spring security.

Apologies for asking what is probably a basic architecture question but i'd like to get this right (whilst not go too complicated with OAuth if possible)

Answer (score 1):

If your JWT token is signed by the web microservice it may share the public key with other microservices like user-account microservice. This will allow other micro-services to do authentication using the existing JWT token but not generate a new one. 
To use JWT correctly you need to ensure that JWT token has a limited expiration time and JWT token body doesn't contain any sensitive information.